# Reordering p:dataTable rows containing inputs

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

There is `p:dataTable` with `p:inputText` in a column:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{rowReorder.dataList}" 
                 var="row" draggableRows="true" rowKey="#{row.id}">
        <p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="#{rowReorder.reorder}" update="dataTable"/>

        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:commandButton value="Add" actionListener="#{rowReorder.addData}" 
                                 update="dataTable" process="dataTable"/>
            </f:facet>
            <p:outputLabel value="#{row.id}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:inputText value="#{row.name}"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Backing bean:

```
import org.omnifaces.cdi.ViewScoped;
import org.primefaces.event.ReorderEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

@Named("rowReorder")
@ViewScoped
public class RowReorder implements Serializable {

    private List<Data> dataList = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addData() {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setId(dataList.size() + 1);
        data.setName("Data " + data.getId());
        dataList.add(data);
    }

    public void reorder(ReorderEvent event) {

    }

    /**
     * Getters, Setters
     */

    public List<Data> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

Data class:

```
public class Data implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    /**
     * Getters, Setters
     */

}
```

Sample datatable before reordering:

```
--------------
|id |  name  |
--------------
| 1 | Data 1 |
| 2 | Data 2 |
| 3 | Data 3 |
| 4 | Data 4 |
--------------
```

and after reordering (moving 1-st row to 3-rd):

```
--------------
|id |  name  |
--------------
| 2 | Data 1 |
| 3 | Data 2 |
| 1 | Data 3 |
| 4 | Data 4 |
--------------
```

I understand that it is happening 'cause of setting data from `p:inputText`'s at `UPDATE_MODEL` phase. I tried to prevent processing of input fields by specifying `process="@none"` in `p:ajax` component, but it doesn't work. Have any idea how to make `draggableRows` and `p:inputText` friends?

Comment: Debugging shows that rotating of `dataList` occurs on `APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES` phase in `decode()` of `org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.DraggableRowsFeature`. And setting values of inputs occurs later on `UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES` phase, to already reordered `dataList`, and that is a problem.

Comment: Just guessing but try to implement equals() and hashCode() in Data

Comment: I did it. just didn't show. its default....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## First solution

I found a solution!
It does not processing inputs (and actually does not submit it at all) with attributes `process="@none" partialSubmit="true"`

So complete p:ajax component looks like
`<p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="#{rowReorder.reorder}" update="dataTable" process="@none" partialSubmit="true"/>`

---

## Second solution (if submitted data is needed)

### Theory:

Lets check out what is happening on dragging row?
We have ajax request forcing `process="form:dataTable"`. On APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES phase `DataTableRenderer` tries to invoke decode of `DraggableRowsFeature` which, in turn, rotating list elements (list that specified as dataTable's value attribute). So on UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES phase we have a rotated list, and input components, which wants to submit their values to `name` fields of `Data` objects. But request parameters still contains old row indexes in input ids: they are `form:dataTable:1:name = Data 2`, `form:dataTable:2:name = Data 3`, `form:dataTable:0:name = Data 1` (i added 3 rows, and moved first row to last). So here we getting what we got. In this way if we need data to be submitted on right places we have to prevent our list rotating before UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES is done, 
and perform this rotation later on INVOKE_APPLICATION phase, and render dataTable on that ajax request:

In `DraggableRowsFeature.decode()` we can see that `Collections.rotate()` is calling only when value is instance of List.

```
    if (value instanceof List) {
        List list = (List) value;

        if(toIndex >= fromIndex) {
            Collections.rotate(list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex + 1), -1);
        }
        else {
            Collections.rotate(list.subList(toIndex, fromIndex + 1), 1);
        }            
    } 
    else {
        LOGGER.info("Row reordering is only available for list backed datatables, use rowReorder ajax behavior with listener for manual handling of model update.");
    }
```

Also there is `DraggableRowsFeature.shouldDecode()` method.

```
public boolean shouldDecode(FacesContext context, DataTable table) {
    return context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().containsKey(table.getClientId(context) + "_rowreorder");
}
```

So here we have 2 possibilities to prevent datasource rotating:

1. Don't use `List` as dataTable value
2. Create own `org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.DraggableRowsFeature` returning false in `shouldDecode()` method.

### Practice:

I modified bean file like this:

```
@Named("rowReorder")
@ViewScoped
public class RowReorder implements Serializable {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RowReorder.class);
    private Set<Data> dataList = new LinkedHashSet<>();


    public void addData() {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setId(dataList.size() + 1);
        data.setName("Data " + data.getId());
        dataList.add(data);
        log.warn("{} {}", Integer.toHexString(data.hashCode()), data.getId());
    }

    public void removeData(Data data) {
        dataList.remove(data);
    }

    public void reorder(ReorderEvent event) {
        List<Data> list = new LinkedList<>(dataList);

        int fromIndex = event.getFromIndex();
        int toIndex = event.getToIndex();
        if(toIndex >= fromIndex) {
            Collections.rotate(list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex + 1), -1);
        }
        else {
            Collections.rotate(list.subList(toIndex, fromIndex + 1), 1);
        }
        dataList.clear();
        dataList.addAll(list);
    }

    /**
     * Getters, Setters
     */

    public Set<Data> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

And now it firstly submitting values to model and rotating list on INVOKE_APPLICATION phase.

Comment: I'm not sure this the is best solution, but it's working.

Comment: if you edit rows afterwards, does it still work? No errors?

Comment: It will work, but you need to submit previously entered data to ViewRoot. For example 
`<p:inputText value="#{row.name}">
    <p:ajax process="@this" update="@this"/>
</p:inputText>`

Comment: your solution is quite neat. the same problem applies if your try to use datatable filters. your solution should work in this case as well

Comment: added another working solution, based on understanding workflow of things happening.

Comment: @PatrykDobrowolski I'm glad it was helpful. Most idiotic thing in JSF is storing client state on server, but having no much deal with HTML and all of this things, which JSF UI Components gives us, sometimes outweigh... :)

Comment: Thanks! This answer was helpful!
It's not the prettiest method but it works!

I have used the second solution.

Comment: How should option 2 work? I do not see any option to plugin a custom datatable feature besides hacking the DataTableRenderer? Any help appreciated.

Comment: How do I register the custom DraggableRowsFeature in the FacesConfig.xml?

Comment: @lastresort it is not possible as it is no faces component in its way to be extendible. I did not find any way to register a custom DraggableRowsFeature without hacking the primefaces source...

Comment: Using a Set instead of a List actually worked. Thank You !

Comment: I use primefaces 6.2, couldn't make it work with events manipulation neither usind this WA: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5326. WHAT WORKED for me was setting skipChildren="true", BUT using it had some side effects, like my download link inside the table stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

The secret is the attribute `rowStatePreserved` of your datatable, add it:

**rowStatePreserved="true"**

```
 <p:dataTable id="dataTable" value="#{rowReorder.dataList}" 
              var="row" draggableRows="true" rowKey="#{row.id}" 
              rowStatePreserved="true">
```

And keep this code as like:

```
<p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="#{rowReorder.reorder}" update="dataTable" process="@this"/>
```

In my case i was used a combobox into datatable column, and after i added this atrribute the value do not change more than one row to another when i used draggableRows function.

I wait help you.

Answer (score 0):

Other simple solution is to disable the inputs on the start of `rowReorder`:

```html
<p:ajax event="rowReorder"
        onstart="$(':input', PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('#{component.clientId}')).prop('disabled',true)"
        update="@this"/>
```

Note that `#{component.clientId}` will return the client ID of the data table.

To avoid loosing data, you can Ajaxify the inputs:

```html
<p:column headerText="#{msg.value}">
  <p:inputText value="#{item.value}">
    <p:ajax/>
  </p:inputText>
</p:column>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem using Primefaces 12.

Saddly the solutions above doesn't work for me, so i've to find another option:

Primefaces 12 offers the attribute draggableRowsFunction on the p:datatable element.
If set, the default behavior described by antonu17 in his second solution is disabled. (see org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.DraggableRowsFeature.decode(...))

This means the submit is processed normaly, including the correct model update in UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES-Phase. After that you can use the ajax event "rowReorder" with a listener method to get the ReorderEvent-Object with from/to index and shift the order in the list yourself.

That worked for me.

(Primefaces 7 worked fine with the first solution of antonu17)